# Uber API for login page, option for Login using Facebook does not work?

Tags: ios, facebook, uber-api

I am using Uber API for my application, I am trying uber login and i am successfully logging in using uber credentials. But if i click on the Facebook login button, it does not work

I am using this url for user login

```
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&scope=request%20profile%20history&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>.
```

It shows me the facebook button for login using Facebook but it doesn't work.

[image: Uber Authentication Url with Facebook login]

Comment: What exactly is your error message? Do you have console logs you can share? Maybe you're using a browser extension that disables facebook login?

Comment: i have added the image for understanding.

Comment: It doesn't go anywhere, basically no action happens.

Comment: Have you also set up the facebook api properly? Are you using swift?

Comment: i didnt used any facebook api and i am using objective c.that url no even redirect to facebook.nor gives any eventto handle.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the issue? What when you click "Continue with Facebook"?

Comment: We were working on this issue and as we came to know that this "Continue with Facebook" button Works in the mobile Browser but not in webview or mac web browser. On the mobile browser It redirects us to m.facebook.com and works perfectly. On the MacOS browser & webiew of the application nothing happens on clicking the FB login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i Come to know that.uber facebook login only works for mobile browser.I was trying to load login site into desktop browser or nswebview from my application, which will not work because it needs facebook integration.